# Reduce memory consumption by delphi application

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, ihtmldocument2

I have in my one thread system that receives an html a TIdHttp and treats this html with IHTMLDocument2 as below:

```
 if IDocTabela = nil then
    IDocTabela := CreateComObject(Class_HTMLDOcument) as IHTMLDocument2
 else
    IDocTabela.clear;

 IDocTabela.designMode := 'on';
 if IENovo = False then
  while IDocTabela.readyState <> 'complete' do
     Application.ProcessMessages;

 v := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], VarVariant);
 v[0] := xHtml;
 IDocTabela.Write(PSafeArray(System.TVarData(v).VArray));
 IDocTabela.designMode := 'off';
 if IENovo = False then
  while IDocTabela.readyState <> 'complete' do
     Application.ProcessMessages;

 for q := 0 to (IDocTabela.all.tags('TABLE') as IHTMLElementCollection).Length -1 do
    begin
      ovTable := (IDocTabela.all.tags('TABLE') as IHTMLElementCollection).item(q, 0);

      for i := 0 to (ovTable.Rows.Length - 1) do
        begin
          for j := 0 to (ovTable.Rows.Item(i).Cells.Length - 1) do
            begin
              sTemp := TrimRight(TrimLeft(ovTable.Rows.Item(I).Cells.Item(J).InnerText));
              if (sTemp = 'Item') = true then
                 begin
                  bSai := True;
                  Break;
                 end;
            end;
            if bSai = True then
              Break;
        end;
      if bSai = True then
        Break;
    end;
```

My problem is that this code is executed every 3 seconds, and every time this code executes, the memory consumption increases in 1.000k with this application will consume a lot of memory and slowing down over time until it locks, the two lines that make the memory increases are:

```
 IDocTabela.Write(PSafeArray(System.TVarData(v).VArray));
```

and

```
ovTable := (IDocTabela.all.tags('TABLE') as IHTMLElementCollection).item(q, 0);
```

Note: I always destroy the IHTMLDocument2 component created with FreeAndNil()
Any idea how to improve this code, so that this memory consumption stop occur?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this code executing in a thread? Application.ProcessMessages don't belong here.

Comment: Have you verified the leak using something like FastMM in full debug mode, or are you relying on figures from Task Manager?

Comment: This code is inside a thread, but this procedure is called within a thread, I'm checking the memory by the task manager, now I discovered a detail, this problem only occurs when you have IE 9 or higher, with IE 8 does not. tested with win8 IE11 the problem happens, win7 IE11 also happens, win7 64bit, Win XP and Win 7 32bit with IE 8 the problem does not happen. a bug with new versions of IE?

Comment: Why do you call ProcessMessages? Can we have a simple MCVE?

Comment: David, The application.processmessage is only necessary with version 8 of IE, because the document is not loaded if you do not, any other suggestions?

Comment: ProcessMessages is certainly not needed.

Answer (score 4):

> I always destroy the IHTMLDocument2 component created with FreeAndNil()

You cannot do that.  There is no `IHTMLDocument2` **component**.  You are creating an instance of a COM object that implements the `IHTMLDocument2` **interface**, and that interface is reference-counted.  Its underlying implementation object is not based on `TObject` (since it is not written in Delphi to begin with).  An interface frees its underlying object automatically when its reference count falls to 0.  Just let the variable go out of scope.  If you must decrement the reference count manually, set the interface to `nil` instead using `FreeAndNil()`:

```
IDocTabela := CreateComObject(Class_HTMLDOcument) as IHTMLDocument2
...
IDocTabela := nil;
```

That being said, there is another way to load HTML into an `IHTMLDocument2` - query it for the `IPersistStreamInit` interface and then call its `Load()` method, which takes an `IStream` as input.  No need for putting the docuent into design mode, or processing window messages.  You can get an `IStream` for your HTML by putting your HTML into a `TStringStream` or `TMemoryStream` and then wrap it inside a `TStreamAdapter`.